# Cassandra select rows based on date range

Tags: cassandra, date-range, cql3

This is my scenario, I have table business which has following columns, code,name,description,datetime. Now I need to show code and name of those business records which has datetime greater than current system date time.
What strategy should I adopt so that cassandra's can give best ready performance for above scenario.

Thanks
Ani

Comment: what do you mean by strategy ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the sizes of your data but since you want query by datetime and you want range, this particular column should be your last clustering column. This will ensure that you can query by it and also that you can do a range search. Remember that in cassandra if you do a range search in some column your query ends right away.

Example:

**Valid Query**
select * from table where column1 = something1 and column2 = something2 and datetime > now;

**Invalid Query**
select * from table where column1 = something1 and column2 < something2 and datetime > now;

If you need more details or help you could provide us with your data sizes and more info about your use case.
In any case this [course from datastax](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling) helped me a lot with the modeling process. I recommend it 100%. It is free. You only need to sign up.

Comment: Thanks Reveka for your reply. In my requirement I cannot use any other columns as suggested by you (column1, column2), why because only datetime column is allowed for filtering the data.
  Have you used "SSTable Attached Secondary Index (SASI)" which allow to perform range query with out specifying primary column.

Comment: Yes but I would not recommend it. It has a pretty unpredictable behaviour (at least in my use case). So to get things straight, your only search option is the datetime?

Comment: Hi Reveka,
     Yes my search option has only datetime, because the use case says, on web page's drop down I have to show only those business codes which has datetime greater than current datetime (as other business codes which has datetime in the past are expired business codes)

Comment: How many rows does a query like that typically return? If the number of rows is small (like a couple of thousands at most) then all your data can be stored in one partition. This would mean that you have to use a pseudo-key as the partition column. For example let's say you would make the first column to be a tinyint and then you would make the second column to be the date (clustering column). Then your queries would all be like this: **Select * from table where pseudokey = 1 and date > '2016-08-12'**

Comment: Yea I could take above approach. Will it become single point of failure for my application, in case the node that is holding all the data for this table crashes?

Comment: You could add a replication factor and have this data in multiple nodes. It's up to you.